# cant get li link to be correct color on not hovering works with hovering

Tags: html, css

I get the white color on hovering and all other syling works, its just in its static position it is still having the standard color. I have looked over and over I just cant see it!

the css

```
    .MainMenu li{
display: inline;
margin-left: 0px;
text-decoration:none;
height: 35px;
color: #ffffff;
}
.MainMenu :link{
text-decoration:none;
margin-left: 0px;
height: 35px;
font-size: 24px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
color: #ffffff;
}
.MainMenu :hover {
background: #34a4f8;
text-decoration: none;
height: 35px;
color: white;
}
.MainMenu {
padding-left:0px;
}
p.MainMenu {
color:#ffffff;
}
```

the html

```
<p class='MainMenu'>
<ul class="MainMenu">
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</p>
```

Comment: What you are asking is not clear at all. You say: `its just in its static position`. `static` is a specific css positioning setting and it confounds your question. Be more detailed in your explanation. For example, `when I hover over Home I expect X, but Y happens.`

Answer (score 0):

To echo the comments from @mrtsherman, it's not clear what you want.

But this will help in your testing, I believe: 
instead of `<a href="">`, try testing with `<a href="#">`.